# how to get variabel value in other block in php

Tags: php

> I have a source code like this

```
    <?php
    //block1
    $a=0;
    $b=0;
    $c=0;
    echo "a".$a."<br>";
    echo "b".$a."<br>";
    echo "c".$a."<br>";
    ?>


    <?php
//block 2
    $a=7;
    $b=8;
    $c=9; 
    ?>
```

> how to display value of variabel a,b,c  in block 2 from block 1?

Comment: Like you printed them in block 1 ?!

Comment: You are redifining the variables in block two. so the original $a will be changed to the new $a

Comment: if I echo in block 1 the output is :
a=0
b=0
c=0
i need 
a=7
b=8
c=9

Comment: That is not possible. The code runs from top to bottom and not the other way around.

Comment: put block 2 after the variables?

Comment: variabel a,b,c is global scope I think  php can't set value without '$'

Comment: Put the html between block 1 and block 2 in a php variable. This way you can execute everything together and print later in the order you prefer.

Comment: it' work  @Rajdeep Paul :D

Comment: @Alimin Happy to hear. Please mark it as *accepted*. :)

Comment: @ Rajdeep Paul,how to doing that?, I already upvote your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by controlling the flow of execution using [`goto`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php), like this:

```
<?php
    //block1
    $a = 0;
    $b = 0;
    $c = 0;
    goto location1;

    location2:
    echo "a = ".$a."<br>";
    echo "b = ".$b."<br>";
    echo "c = ".$c."<br>";
    goto location3;
?>

<?php
    location1:
    //block 2
    $a=7;
    $b=8;
    $c=9;
    goto location2;

    location3:
    echo "execution continues...";
?>
```

Output:

```
a = 7
b = 8
c = 9
execution continues...
```

**Sidenote:** Don't use too many `goto` statements in your code because it'll make your code unreadable for future maintainers.

Comment: It's more like a *caution* than a sidenote. :)

Comment: make it sound the alarm bells and whistles like it's the fourth of july when doing `gotos`

Comment: @Alimin Learn about `goto` now. It comes quite handy sometimes.

Comment: I learn new technique if I get the  case bro, thank to your advice

Comment: @Alimin You're very welcome! Now please mark this answer *accepted* so that it could be useful for future SO users. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create new variables for the second block so that the first blocks variables will keep their values.

Something like this

```
<?php
    //block1
    $a=0;
    $b=0;
    $c=0;
    echo "a".$a."<br>";
    echo "b".$a."<br>";
    echo "c".$a."<br>";
    ?>


    <?php
//block 2
    $a2=7;
    $b2=8;
    $c2=9;

    echo "a".$a."<br>";
    echo "b".$a."<br>";
    echo "c".$a."<br>";


    echo "a".$a2."<br>";
    echo "b".$a2."<br>";
    echo "c".$a2."<br>"; 
    ?>
```